# jqueryUI functions fail to be found when php require_once is used for common script components in page

Tags: php, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, require-once

When attempting to include the jquery library via a php require_once() I find that invocations of the .dialog() component of JQuery UI produce an error message:

> $("#dialog").dialog is not a function

This seemed strange to me as upon inspecting the DOM I see that the expected html tag is rendered namely:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/scripts/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" type="text/css" />
```

does anyone know why including the html fragment via php's require_once/include_once would cause this problem?

Answer (score 2):

A **server-side** php's require_once/include_once has **ABSOLUTELY. NOTHING. TO DO** with whatever HTML issues on the **client side**.

This is most basic rule a web-developer have to learn.

You have to find out a client side issue and fix it.

Always treat any HTML/JS outputted via PHP as native HTML/JS.
There is no difference on the client side.

The algorithm of spotting down the problem is always the same:

1. Create a clean client-based code with no PHP at all.
2. **Make it work**
3. Let PHP output this code.
4. If something goes wrong - **COMPARE THE CODES**. Find out the differencies.
5. Correct them.